# CSS not staying centered when div disappears

Tags: html, css, iphone, mobile

Hello so I'm trying to center a div in the middle of the screen between 2 div that disappear on mobile device.
I can center it when the divs are loaded, but when I am replacing them with new ones the middle div goes of the top.

```css
    #container{
     text-align: center;
     display: flex;
     align-items: flex-end;
     justify-content: center;
     animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 fadeIn;
     }
    .middle {
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      z-index: 3;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      position: absolute;
      display: flex;
    }
```

```html
        <div class="middle">
        <p id="middle">VS</p>
        <p id="middle-circle"></p>
    </div>
        <div id="container" >
            <div class="box">image</div>
            <div class="box">image</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you post two sketches that show what you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

not quite clear what you are asking but if you wrap this whole think in a big container and add a little css the following should work,.

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 fadeIn;
}

.middle {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
}

#big{
height:100vh;
display:relative;
}
```

```html
<div id ='big'>
<div class="middle">
  <p id="middle">VS</p>
  <p id="middle-circle"></p>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">image</div>
  <div class="box">image</div>
</div> 
</div>
```